# Displaying various .pdf documents that a user uploads

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pdf

I need to find a way to display the various documents a user may upload.  The view below shows code that will display a certain document named piano.pdf, which is written in the code.  This code will display the document piano.pdf.  Is there a way to replace piano.pdf with a variable that will display various pdf’s located in the file system?
I have included code in the view, model and the controller method that calls the view.

View:

```
@model TheExchangeI.ViewModels.UserDocumentViewModel

@{
   `enter code here` ViewBag.Title = "DisplayDocument";
}

<h2>DisplayDocument</h2>

<div class="col-md-8">

 <embed src="~/Content/UserDocuments/piano.pdf" width="100%" height="375" type="application/pdf">


        <p>
            <label></label>
        </p>

    </div>
```

Model:

```
namespace TheExchangeI.Models
{
    public class UserDocument
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "File")]
        [StringLength(100)]

        public string FileName { get; set; }




        public string UserNumber { get; set; } 

    }
}
```

Controller Method:

```
public ActionResult DisplayDocument() //  (int id)
     {

         return View();


     }
```

Comment: `Directory.GetFiles("/content/userdocuments")` returns list of all files in the given path

Comment: And to get the correct directory for your uploaded content, use Server.MapPath.